# gmap coordinates convert to string

Tags: java, google-maps, jsf, primefaces

I use gmap in my web project. I have code snippet code:

```
<p:gmap id="harita" center="#{KoordinatEdit.istasyon.lat},#{KoordinatEdit.istasyon.lng}" zoom="15" type="HYBRID" model="#{KoordinatEdit.simpleModel}" style="width:600px;height:400px">  
    <p:ajax event="markerDrag" listener="#{KoordinatEdit.onMarkerDrag}" update="messages,harita" />
</p:gmap>

Marker marker=event.getMarker();
istasyon.setLat(String.format("%.10g%n",marker.getLatlng().getLat()));
istasyon.setLng(String.format("%.10g%n",marker.getLatlng().getLng()));
FacesUtil.addMessage("Lat:" + latlng.getLat() + ", Lng:" + latlng.getLng(), FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
```

On my local server it works, String.format returns coordinate like '37.8709573', but upload to web server String.format changes coordinate like 37,8709573 with comma. For this reason gmap center has errors.

How can I solve this problem? Any idea is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't figure out the issue with the reformat you could always just replace the comma with a period?

```
str = str.replaceAll(",",".");
```